# Magento to Magento order import

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I need to migrate orders table from one magento website to another magento website.

I have figured out tables in which table magento stores customer and order data.

```
'customer_address_entity'
'customer_address_entity_datetime'
'customer_address_entity_decimal'
'customer_address_entity_int'
'customer_address_entity_text'
'customer_address_entity_varchar'
'customer_eav_attribute'
'customer_eav_attribute_website'
'customer_entity'
'customer_entity_datetime'
'customer_entity_decimal'
'customer_entity_int'
'customer_entity_text'
'customer_entity_varchar'
'customer_form_attribute'
'customer_group'
'sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily';
'sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly';
'sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly';
'sales_billing_agreement';
'sales_billing_agreement_order';
'sales_flat_creditmemo';
'sales_flat_creditmemo_comment';
'sales_flat_creditmemo_grid';
'sales_flat_creditmemo_item';
'sales_flat_invoice';
'sales_flat_invoice_comment';
'sales_flat_invoice_grid';
'sales_flat_invoice_item';
'sales_flat_order';
'sales_flat_order_address';
'sales_flat_order_grid';
'sales_flat_order_item';
'sales_flat_order_payment';
'sales_flat_order_status_history';
'sales_flat_quote';
'sales_flat_quote_address';
'sales_flat_quote_address_item';
'sales_flat_quote_item';
'sales_flat_quote_item_option';
'sales_flat_quote_payment';
'sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate';
'sales_flat_shipment';
'sales_flat_shipment_comment';
'sales_flat_shipment_grid';
'sales_flat_shipment_item';
'sales_flat_shipment_track';
'sales_invoiced_aggregated';
'sales_invoiced_aggregated_order';
'sales_order_aggregated_created';
'sales_order_aggregated_updated';
'sales_order_status';
'sales_order_status_label';
'sales_order_status_state';
'sales_order_tax';
'sales_order_tax_item';
'sales_payment_transaction';
'sales_recurring_profile';
'sales_recurring_profile_order';
'sales_refunded_aggregated';
'sales_refunded_aggregated_order';
'sales_shipping_aggregated';
'sales_shipping_aggregated_order';
```

But i don't know how I can do this, I have tried used to ignoring table but that's not working either.

Please let me know how should i proceed.

Comment: there is a magento import/export tool..

Comment: Are both Magento setups using the same version of Magento? Does the target site have orders and customers that you need to preserve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following extension may help you.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-import-export-orders-to-csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Select these tables and export them; then import in the other DB. If you are not very good in MySql you can use GUI tools like [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).